# Python to print final results at begin

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to print final results at the beginning.

Below is the python script:

```html
fail_count = 0
pass_count = 0
a = "A"
b = "B"
if a == "A" and b == "B":
    print "QA_check1 | Passed"
    pass_count += 1
else:
    print "QA_check1 | Failed"
    fail_count += 1
c = "C"
d = "Z"
if c == "c" and d == "D":
    print "QA_check1 | Passed"
    pass_count += 1
else:
    print "QA_check1 | Failed"
    fail_count += 1

total_qa = pass_count + fail_count
print "Total QA Performed {}".format(total_qa)
print "Total QA Passed {}".format(pass_count)
print "Total QA Failed {}".format(fail_count)
```

and Below is the output:

```
QA_check1 | Passed
QA_check1 | Failed
Total QA Performed 2
Total QA Passed 1
Total QA Failed 1
```

But I am expecting an output as shown below. Please help me in achieving this:

```
 Total QA Performed 2
 Total QA Passed 1
 Total QA Failed 1 
 QA_check1 | Passed
 QA_check1 | Failed
```

Comment: You can store your `QA_check1` outputs in a variable and then print it at the end.

Comment: @gopinara Once you have found a solution which works for you, please click the tick next to that answer to accept it. This lets other people with your problem know which solution works for you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you had is

```
if a == "A" and b == "B":
    print "QA_check1 | Passed"
    pass_count += 1
else:
    print "QA_check1 | Failed"
    fail_count += 1
c = "C"
d = "Z"
if c == "c" and d == "D":
    print "QA_check1 | Passed"
    pass_count += 1
else:
    print "QA_check1 | Failed"
    fail_count += 1
```

notice how you told it to print in the two if and else statements. These statements were before the

```
total_qa = pass_count + fail_count
print "Total QA Performed {}".format(total_qa)
print "Total QA Passed {}".format(pass_count)
print "Total QA Failed {}".format(fail_count)
```

that means it will come before it so the result that you got is what you coded for.
If you want the result that you want I would recommend changing the print in the two if statements to a two different variables. For example you can do this

```
if a == "A" and b == "B":
    QA_check1_a_and_b="QA_check1 | Passed"
    pass_count += 1
else:
    QA_check1_a_and_b="QA_check1 | Failed"
    fail_count += 1
c = "C"
d = "Z"
if c == "c" and d == "D":
    QA_check1_c_and_d="QA_check1 | Passed"
    pass_count += 1
else:
    QA_check1_c_and_d="QA_check1 | Failed"
    fail_count += 1
```

then at the end you say:

```
total_qa = pass_count + fail_count
print "Total QA Performed {}".format(total_qa)
print "Total QA Passed {}".format(pass_count)
print "Total QA Failed {}".format(fail_count)
print "QA_check1_a_and_b
print "QA_check1_c_and_d
```

this way it comes how how you wanted it too.

Next time always remember that python runs the order that you code it not the order that you want it to go. Also remember that when you tell it to print it will actually print :).

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to store the `QACheck1` results in two variables and then `print()` them at the end.

```
fail_count = 0
pass_count = 0

a = "A"
b = "B"
QACheck1Str1 = ""

if a == "A" and b == "B":
    QACheck1Str1 = "QA_check1 | Passed"
    pass_count += 1
else:
    QACheck1Str1 = "QA_check1 | Failed"
    fail_count += 1


c = "C"
d = "Z"

QACheck1Str2 = ""

if c == "c" and d == "D":
    QACheck1Str2 = "QA_check1 | Passed"
    pass_count += 1
else:
    QACheck1Str2 = "QA_check1 | Failed"
    fail_count += 1




total_qa = pass_count + fail_count
print "Total QA Performed {}".format(total_qa)
print "Total QA Passed {}".format(pass_count)
print "Total QA Failed {}".format(fail_count)
print QACheck1Str1
print QACheck1Str2
```

**Output:**

```
Total QA Performed 2
Total QA Passed 1
Total QA Failed 1 
QA_check1 | Passed
QA_check1 | Failed
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of code duplication in your solution.
Hence, I think you'd better define a tailor-made Test class as follows:

```
class Test():
    def __init__(self, prefix = 'QA_check1 | '):
        self.fail_count = 0
        self.pass_count = 0
        self.prefix = prefix
        self.answers = []

    def equality_test_fails(self):
        self.fail_count += 1
        self.answers.append('Failed')

    def equality_test_passes(self):
        self.pass_count += 1 
        self.answers.append('Passed')

    def equals_on_iterable(self, equality_iterable):
        for ei in equality_iterable:
            if ei[0] != ei[1]:
                self.equality_test_fails()
                return
        self.equality_test_passes()

    def print_report(self):
        self.print_kpis()
        self.print_details()

    def print_kpis(self):
        print "Total QA Performed {}".format(self.pass_count + self.fail_count)
        print "Total QA Passed {}".format(self.pass_count)
        print "Total QA Failed {}".format(self.fail_count)

    def print_details(self):
        for a in self.answers:
            print(self.prefix + a)
```

Then, the main part is much more readable and changeable than the current one:

```
a = "A"
b = "B"
c = "C"
d = "Z"

test = Test()

test.equals_on_iterable([(a, "A"), (b, "B")])
test.equals_on_iterable([(c, "C"), (d, "D")])
test.print_report()
```

In the end, the data is printed as wanted:

```
Total QA Performed 2
Total QA Passed 1
Total QA Failed 1
QA_check1 | Passed
QA_check1 | Failed
```

Please feel free to comment on this code if you have any idea on how we could improve it :)